# How do you write the laravel 5 code to download images

Tags: download, laravel-5.1

I'm wondering if someone can point me in the right direction. I would like for clients to be able to download pictures and for them to go into a mysql database. I'm really confused on how to write the laravel 5 code for that...and for some reason aren't able to find what I need when I use google. Can anyone give me some advice or point me to a good website that can lay it all out for me?

Thanks bunches,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing code for downloading files is easy with Laravel 5. Its as simple as

```
return response()->download($pathToFile);
```

in your `DownloadController` method. Here is the link to the doc: [HTTP Responses](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/responses#file-downloads).

But I didn't understand the part where *clients to be able to ... go into mysql database*. Why would you want your visitors to go into your MySQL database. Don't you think its a *little insecure*?